# C++ Не могу исправить ошибку. При открытии файла создается лишняя нулевая строка в списке

Tags: c++, списки

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Toy
{public:
    char name[30];
    float cost;
    int count;
    int min_age;
    int max_age;
    Toy *prev, *next;
    Toy()
    {
        strcpy(name, "");
        cost=0;
        count=0;
        min_age=0;
        max_age=0;
        prev=NULL;
        next=NULL;
    }
};
class ToyShop
{
public:
    Toy *begin, *end;
    ToyShop()
    {
        begin=end=NULL;
    }
    ~ToyShop()
    {   Toy *rex;
        while(begin)
        {
            rex=begin;
            begin=begin->next;
            delete rex;
        }

    }
    void ShowToyNext(void);
    void ShowToyPrev(void);
    void FileOpenToy(void);
    void FileSaveToy(void);
    void AddToy(void);
};
void Menu(void)
{
    ToyShop M;
    int key=0;
    cout<<"Create list from file? [1-yes; 2-no]\nPress any key..."<<endl;
    key=_getch();
    if(key==49)
        M.FileOpenToy();

        key=0;
        while (key!=27)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Menu:"<<endl;
            cout<<"\t1-Add Toy\n\t2-Show Toy->\n\t3-Show Toy<-\n"<<endl;
            cout<<"Esc-exit"<<endl;
            cout<<"\n Press any key..."<<endl;
            key=_getch();
            if(key==49)
                 M.AddToy();
            if(key==50)
                 M.ShowToyNext();
            if(key==51)
                M.ShowToyPrev();     
        }
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Create list from file? [1-yes; 2-no]\nPress any key..."<<endl;
        key=_getch();
        if(key==49)
          M.FileSaveToy();

}

void ToyShop::AddToy(void)
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\t\t\tAdd Toy"<<endl;
    Toy *rex=new Toy;
    if(!rex)exit(1);
    cout<<"\tname="; cin>>rex->name;
    cout<<"\tcost="; cin>>rex->cost;
    cout<<"\tcount="; cin>>rex->count;
    cout<<"\tmin_age="; cin>>rex->min_age;
    cout<<"\tmax_age="; cin>>rex->max_age;
    if(begin==NULL)
         begin=rex;
    else
    {
        end->next=rex;
        rex->prev=end;
    }
    end=rex;
    cout<<"\nPress any key..."<<endl;
    _getch();       
}

void ToyShop::ShowToyNext(void)
{
    system("cls");
    Toy *rex;
    cout<<"\t\t\tShow Toy"<<endl;
    if(!begin)
    {
        cout<<"\tList toy is empty!"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nPressany key..."<<endl;
        _getch();
        return;
    }
    rex=begin;
    cout<<"name\t\tcost\t\tcount\t\tmin_age\t\tmax_age"<<endl;
    while(rex)
    {
        cout<<rex->name<<(strlen(rex->name)>7?"\t":"\t\t")<<rex->cost<<"\t\t"<<rex->count<<"\t\t"<<rex->min_age<<"\t\t"<<rex->max_age<<endl;
        rex=rex->next;    
    }
    cout<<"\nPressany key..."<<endl;
    _getch();
}

void ToyShop::ShowToyPrev(void)
{
    system("cls");
    Toy *rex;
    cout<<"\t\t\tShow Toy"<<endl;
    if(!begin)
    {
        cout<<"\tList toy is empty!"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nPressany key..."<<endl;
        _getch();
        return;
    }
    rex=end;
    cout<<"\tname\t\tcost\t\tcount\t\tmin_age\t\tmax_age"<<endl;
    while(rex)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<rex->name<<(strlen(rex->name)>7?"\t":"\t\t")
            <<rex->cost<<"\t\t"<<rex->count<<"\t\t"<<rex->min_age<<"\t\t"<<rex->max_age<<endl;
        rex=rex->prev;    
    }
    cout<<"\nPressany key..."<<endl;
    _getch();
}

void ToyShop::FileOpenToy(void)
{
      FILE*f=fopen("toybase.dat","rb");

      if(!f)return;

      while(!feof(f))
            {  

        Toy *rex=new Toy;

        fread(&(rex->name),sizeof(rex->name), 1, f);        
        fread(&(rex->cost), sizeof(float),1, f);
        fread(&(rex->count), sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&(rex->min_age), sizeof(int),1, f);
        fread(&(rex->max_age), sizeof(int),1, f);


        if(!begin)
             begin=end=rex;
        else
        {
            end->next=rex;
            rex->prev=end;
        }
       end=rex;        

     }
 fclose(f);         
}
void ToyShop::FileSaveToy(void)
{
      FILE*f=fopen("toybase.dat","wb");
      Toy *rex;
      if(!f)return;
      if(!begin)return;
      rex=begin;
      while(rex)

      {          
        fwrite(&(rex->name),sizeof(rex->name), 1, f);       
        fwrite(&(rex->cost), sizeof(float),1, f);
        fwrite(&(rex->count), sizeof(int),1, f);
        fwrite(&(rex->min_age), sizeof(int),1, f);
        fwrite(&(rex->max_age), sizeof(int),1, f);
                  rex=rex->next;
               }
       fclose(f); 

}

int main()
{
    Menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: у Вас несколько открытий файла. При открытии какого именно создается  и как Вы "это поняли".

Answer (score 3):

Это уже классика...

```
while(!feof(f))
```

Так делать нельзя. `feof(f)` вернет `true` только **после неудачного чтения**, за концом файла. Пока не было попытки читать за концом - `feof(f)` возвращает `false`.